# AngularJS - Sharing data from a parent route controller to all child directives on the page

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I have a page that has multiple components and I've created each component as a directive. When the page is first loaded, that's when I grab all the data that should be available on the page. So all of the data exists on the controller for that route, which we'll just call `pageCtrl`. And then what I've been doing is binding any required data to each directive through the attributes, which of course ends up creating an isolate scope for each of them.

I know there are a few ways to share data, so given this situation, is there a recommended way of doing it? Or has anyone had better success doing it one particular way? While it's working perfectly fine the way I'm doing it, I've run into a few caveats. If I need just even one bit of information from the `pageCtrl`, I need to add another attribute to the directive. So it ends up creating more code on the directive element itself.

I was thinking about just creating a `service` that would store all the data, which the `pageCtrl` could initialize, instead of setting it on itself. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: I think using a Service is the recommended way of sharing data

Comment: If you're using ui-router, a data option is available for every route and is accessible through $state.current. data

Comment: You could just pass an object containing data to the directive scope. Then you don't have to worry about adding more attributes to the directive when there's more data that need to be passed. You simply just add this data to the object by creating a new property in that object. But the best way to pass around data is by using a Service. This will also make sure the data are persistent throughout the application. If that's not the case and you don't want to have persistent data throughout the app, you could try child views instead of directives. These views can access parent's view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

good question :)

1. First solution is to create in parent controller object and pass this object (via ng-model) to all directives. This object will be passed by reference (not by value) so controller and all directives will have access to the same object.

```

```
// in controller
$scope.shared_data = {someItems: []};

// in html
<my-directive ng-model=shared_data></my-directive>
```

2. Second solution is to create some simple service to store all of those data.

   `// in this solution you have to inject additional service to directive controller`
3. (extended idea of point 2) creating service/factory that will be responsible by collecting and returning data. This service could be injected into directive and use the same methods to collect data. To avoid making multiple calls to API (REST) it could have some cache for each sensitive method.
4. Communication via events.... (probably the worsts solution for your example)

The first two ideas are probably the best, I do not know full specification of your product so final solution picking belongs to You:). 
My advice is to try/play with all of those methods to really understand what is going on and how and when to use each of them :)

Comment: Thanks for the input and various ideas. I did indeed go with creating a service, and I set and get the data from there. As you said, this needs to be injected into each directive's controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly call your parent controller from child directive controller by using `$parent`.

```
   App.controller('aCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                           $scope.refresh=function(){
                               ..........  //Updated Data get from DB
                              };
                               ...........
                          }]);

   App.directive('bDirective',function(){
                    restrict: 'EC',
                    replace: true,
                    scope: {},
                    controller: function($scope) {
                        $scope.$parent.refresh();
                    } 
                     ...
            });


    HTML:
    <div ng-controller="aCtrl">
         <div class="bDirective"></div> //directive
    </div>
```